# Is it possible to know what record is being inserted / executed at the current instance?

Tags: mongodb

I have huge collection of records inside mongoDB (300000 approx) 
I have a bash script which runs at a specified time (crontab ) , which is responsible to update / insert the records inside by gathering from a third party server .

I see that that there are no errors during insertion / updation of records (as i didn't find any errors , by using the tail command with grep as Exception )

This script is taking more time than usual , my question is that is it possible to know which symbol is being updated or inserted currently ??

Thanks  in advance .

**Results of my db.currentOp() command operation .**

```
Updated Part


 db.currentOp()
{
        "inprog" : [
                {
                        "opid" : 2981398,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 1,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "JBHTN221465.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44958",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981335,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 6,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "MAING201330.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44964",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981364,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 4,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "symbol" : "WAG"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44939",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981390,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 3,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "QDELX211330.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44928",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981425,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 0,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "UAS201375.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44940",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981428,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 0,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "symbol" : "CAG"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44943",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981370,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 4,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "GASXX211322.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44929",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981379,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 3,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "SAFTS201350.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44972",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981421,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 0,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "symbol" : "YCS"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44934",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981424,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 0,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "symbol" : "DAR"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44960",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                },
                {
                        "opid" : 2981377,
                        "active" : true,
                        "lockType" : "read",
                        "waitingForLock" : true,
                        "secs_running" : 3,
                        "op" : "query",
                        "ns" : "ubsc.symbols",
                        "query" : {
                                "unique_symbol" : "VARN221490.00"
                        },
                        "client" : "12.55.124.208:44968",
                        "desc" : "conn"
                }

        ]
}
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.currentOp()` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/ ) will tell you about in progress operations on the `mongod`

Comment: thanks a lot , i have executed that . From the result obtained , i see that the   "waitingForLock" : true for all results . I was concerned to know , if there is any issue with the attribute waitingForLock" : true ??

Comment: @Kiran It is odd that things are waiting for lock, can you post the results in your question?

Comment: i am updating my question to post the contents . Please see the updated question .

Comment: @Kiran Gotta admit it is kind of odd that ALL operations are waiting for lock, I would have expected at least one to be running. I'll have a play around see if I come up with something